# Из xpath получаю одинаковые значения для разных элементов списка

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

Просматриваю html страничку и хочу из неё достать список, но вместо разных значений получаю несколько одинаковых, число совпадает с общим количеством значений (прим. хочу получить три цены на разные товары, а получаю три одинаковы цена на первый товар)

[вот пример странички для парсинга](http://www.petsonic.com/es/perros/snacks-y-huesos-perro/galletas-granja-para-perro#/)

Пример кода на Ruby:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'

url = 'http://www.petsonic.com/es/perros/snacks-y-huesos-perro/galletas-granja-para-perro'
html = open(url)

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)

names = []
doc.xpath('//div[@class = "attribute_list"]/*' ).each do |row|


    tempName = row.at_xpath('//span[@class = "attribute_name"]')
    tempPrice = row.at_xpath('//span[@class = "attribute_price"]')

    puts tempName
    puts tempPrice
end
```

Плохо знаком с xpath, поэтому прошу подсказать как правильно описать запрос?

Comment: обязательно использовать xpath? или css тоже подходит?

Comment: да нужно использовать именно xpath

Comment: хорошо. Я удалю ответ.

Comment: переделал ответ на xpath

Comment: @MikhailVaysman я попробовал через search 
'row.search('span.attribute_name').text.strip'
и получилось, спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот вариант с xpath

```
(doc / "//ul[@class='attribute_labels_lists']").each do |row|
  tempName = (row / "span[@class='attribute_name']").text.strip
  tempPrice = (row / "span[@class='attribute_price']").text.strip

  puts tempName
  puts tempPrice
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, что вы здесь переусложняете.

Просто (без предварительного `//div[@class = "attribute_list"]/*`) Xpath #1

```
//span[@class = "attribute_name"]
```

и Xpath #2

```
//span[@class = "attribute_price"]
```

дают каждый по три результата.
Почему бы только их и не использовать?

Конкретно по вашему коду: я не знаком с рубишными
либами, но выглядит как буд-то xpath ищется в контексте
всего документа, а не в контексте `row`, поищите в доках
как задается контекст.
Возможно, поможет убрать из 2-го и 3-го xpath запросов
начальные два слеша `//` (т.е. `span[@class = "attribute_name"]`).